# Screenlock = death

Tags: display, suspend, hdmi, ubuntu-studio

So, I'm a newbie and I've loaded Ubuntu Studio (16.04) onto a Compaq 8000 using a "DP Display Port to HDMI Converter" to my LED TV and I'm loving it, EXCEPT for this problem.

When the Display times out (for long periods) I cannot get it back.  If I hit  and/or play with the power button, I can USUALLY get back to the password screen, but can NEVER get back into my locked session   When I type my password it goes blank screen again (it WILL let me in as another user and it works).  Rarely I am never able to revive the display, at all, forcing a power cycle.

I think the problem MAY be limited to ONLY those occasions where the display times out and then the TV turns itself off (from lack of signal - figure 30 mins).

**Quick & Fast:**  I'm willing to "never" suspend the screen if that's what it takes but I can't even find out how to do that, I seem to have a maximum time limit of 60 mins.  I'll be great if somebody can tell me (remember, running ubuntu studio default installation - seems to not offer "never" as a screen timeout)

**For those who love to be problem solvers:**    - Here are some details that MAY be useful based upon what I've browsed, not sure:

```
rick@Ubuntu1:~/.local$ lshw -c video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:1250(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0400000-f04fffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

=========

I also noticed files below (in case it helps)

```
rick@Ubuntu1:~$ cat .xsession-errors
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0

rick@Ubuntu1:~$ cat .xsession-errors.old
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: startxfce4 pre-stop process (14205) killed by TERM signal
upstart: gpg-agent post-stop process (14206) killed by TERM signal
upstart: startxfce4 main process (1622) killed by TERM signal
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
rick@Ubuntu1:~$
```

Anyway, if somebody can point me to a fix that's not too complicated, I can give it a try.  Thanks.